# How do I make ngModelChange not fire if field is not valid because of patern use?

Tags: angular

Having

```
<input matInput  [ngModel]="" type="text" 
pattern="^(?:[0-1]\d|2[0-3]):([0-5]\d):?([0-5]\d)$" 
placeholder="HH:MM:SS" (ngModelChange)="onSetTime($event)">
```

How can I avoid the call of ngModelChange if the field is not valid?

I can do it in onSetTime but I am not sure that is the best way.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Currently you can't configure the `ngModelChange` to emit only when the value is valid. If you check the [docs](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel) you will see that you have some options that you can play around if you look at the `ngModelOptions`:

```
options: {
    name?: string;
    standalone?: boolean;
    updateOn?: FormHooks;
}
```

where:

- name: An alternative to setting the name attribute on the form control element. See the example for using NgModel as a standalone control.
- standalone: When set to true, the ngModel will not register itself with its parent form, and acts as if it's not in the form. Defaults to false. If no parent form exists, this option has no effect.
- updateOn: Defines the event upon which the form control value and validity update. Defaults to 'change'. Possible values: 'change' | 'blur' | 'submit'

So in order to achieve the result you will have to write some additional code.

What I suggest is to write a directive like this one:

```js
import { Directive, EventEmitter, OnDestroy, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { NgModel } from '@angular/forms';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { filter, takeUntil } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appSubmitOnValid][ngModel]'
})
export class SubmitOnValidDirective implements OnDestroy {

  isAlive$ = new Subject();
  @Output() ngModelChangeIfValid: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

  constructor(ngModel: NgModel) {
    ngModel.update.pipe(filter(() => ngModel.valid), takeUntil(this.isAlive$)).subscribe(this.ngModelChangeIfValid);
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.isAlive$.next();
    this.isAlive$.complete();
  }
}
```

and inside the template you can use it on your controls like

```
<input matInput ngModel appSubmitOnValid type="text" 
pattern="^(?:[0-1]\d|2[0-3]):([0-5]\d):?([0-5]\d)$" 
placeholder="HH:MM:SS" (ngModelChangeIfValid)="onSetTime($event)">
```